# How to autofill a field with concatenated other fields Django

Tags: django, database, field, autofill, auto-generate

This is the first time that I ask a question here, so sorry if it's not perfect.

I'm working in django on the last version.

I would like to auto-generate a field (KEY (which will be used in dialogflow)) value when I submit my form with the concatenation of other fields as

```
KEY =  'SENT_' + search_categories + '_' + '001'
```

and I would like that the '001' will be auto-incremented too.

I can't show more code because I'm not sure that it's legal cause I'm working in a private firm but I think that I can show the key declaration in my django model.

```
key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
```

I hope that you'll help me!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate your key in the `save` function of your model :

```
class Model(models.model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    # other attributes...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Only generate key on creating if it was not provided
        if not self.id and not self.key:
            # Get your counter and increment it
            counter = 0
            counter += 1
            # Get search_categories (I don't know what it is)
            search_categories = '?'
            # Use f-string to concatenate the key and add zero pad on the counter
            self.key = f'SENT_{search_categories}_{counter:03}'
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't understand how call or where call this function in my code :/
And what means 'counter:03' ? This permits to auto increments the key ? 
AS SENT_001
SENT_002
SENT_003 ?

Comment: It suppose to be in the definition of your model containing the `key` field. I suggest you to override the `save` function but you can use the logic somewhere else if you want.

Comment: `counter:03` means the counter (which is an int) will be zero padded. So `1` --> `001` ; `54` --> `054`.

Comment: The only thing I don't know is your `search_categories` variable, you didn't tell what is was.

Comment: Owhhhhhh, you are a genious !!!! "search_categories" is a dropdown to choose a quality category, it's just a string to concatenate !

Comment: Ha ha thank you ! If my answer did help you, consider marking it as accepted :)

Comment: I can't test it now cause I have critical things to do before ! But when it's done, I test it !

Comment: I suppose to the save function is in other file, so, I can't override anything. Is there any choice to force the new save function in my KEY declaration ?

Comment: No you cannot do it inside of the KEY declaration. But you should be able to add the save function inside the model where the KEY declaration is. That's how you override it (see this article : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-the-save-method-django-models/)

Comment: Ok i'll do, thanks, I keep you in touch ! Thanks !! :D

Comment: If the fact to add the function "save()" overrides it, it doesn't work for me.. 
I think that I don't understand something. 
We have this in the form

Comment: I had a response to my response (wasn't good to do that, I should to edit my question, sorry)

Comment: Great ! Did you make it work by following the tutorial I sent you (the GeeksForGeeks article) ? Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted in order to close the question !

Comment: Nope, I more understood with your answer and I would like to success myself. Then, I removed the condition "if not self.id" and I put "counter = Sentence.objects.count()". Your answer was very comprehensive and helpful. I thank you so much !